# Async_Dispatch Threads

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading

I am currently making a practice app and was using GCD in it and was having a little big of trouble understanding certain aspects.

I have a question in this code:

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    TWPhotoCollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    //cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    dispatch_queue_t filterQueue = dispatch_queue_create("filter queue", NULL);

    dispatch_async(filterQueue, ^{
        UIImage *filterImage = [self filteredImageFromImage:self.photo.image usingFilter:[self.filters objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            cell.imageView.image = filterImage;
        });
    });

    return cell;
}
```

When you call dispatch_async does that basically switch to the queue I declared or in other words the filterQueue on a separate thread? Also I am calling dispatch_async inside the first dispatch_async to go back to the main queue in order to make some UI changes. Does the second dispatch_async (where I switch to the main queue) get called on the thread of the custom filterQueue I originally created?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you need to move the line that creates the dispatch queue outside of this method.

You should probably only create your dispatch queue once during the life of your program, or at the least only once for the life of your view controller.

You could make filterQueue an instance variable of your view controller and then move the code that creates the queue to your viewDidLoad method.

Then you need to add a dealloc method to your view controller and call dispatch_release on your dispatch queue.

**Now as to your questions**:

dispatch_async submits a block of code for processing on a dispatch queue. In this case you created the target queue using dispatch_queue_create(). If you read the docs for that function they say that if you pass in NULL for the second parameter, you get a serial queue. A serial queue will only run 1 task at a time in FIFO order.

So yes, you are asking that your block of code be run in your serial queue, which runs on a background thread.

That code calls your method `filteredImageFromImage`, which you will need to make sure is thread-safe, and doesn't use/set any instance variables of self.

Once the call to `filteredImageFromImage` is complete, you use a call to `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue())`. This says "From my background thread, submit a block of code to run on the main queue (which runs on the main thread.)"

You have to do this because you can't change UI objects from a background thread. Almost NONE of UIKit is thread-safe. If the code makes a change to a view, it needs to be done on the main thread.

Think of calling dispatch_async with queue other than the main queue as asking an assistant to do some work for you, at the same time that you continue to do your own thing. The assistant runs on a background thread.

You ask the assistant to let you know when the work is done so that you can install it in your view. That's what the call to `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue())` does. It has the background thread invoke code on the main thread.

**Note that your code has a potential problem as written**.

If the call to `filteredImageFromImage` is still running and the user scrolls this cell off-screen, the cell will be recycled to display a different entry in your collection view. However, when `filteredImageFromImage` finishes, the resulting image will be installed into "cell", which was recycled and is now displaying data at a different indexPath.

Instead, you should ask the collection view for the cell at the specified index path, and if it is still available, THEN you should install the image:

```
dispatch_async(filterQueue, ^{
    UIImage *filterImage = [self filteredImageFromImage:self.photo.image usingFilter:[self.filters objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^
    {
      //Ask the collection view for the target cell 
      UICollectionViewCell targetCell = [collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath: indexPath];
      if (targetCell != nil)
        targetCell.imageView.image = filterImage;
    }
    );
});
```

### EDIT:

Note that creating your own queue is not that common. It's more common, easier, and generally more efficient use of system resources, to use one of the existing dispatch queues. You can use the function `dispatch_get_global_queue() to get an existing queue. You might use dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT) or DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH. Using DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH may cause the device to be less responsive, however, so it should be used with care.

Comment: I actually had one more question. What do you mean by "Think of calling dispatch_async with queue other than the main queue as asking an assistant to do some work for you, at the same time that you continue to do your own thing." I don't understand the last part where you say "you can continue to do your own thing". I thought if I passed NULL, it would mean it is a serial queue so I cannot perform any other tasks except for when the filteredImageFromImage method is done calling?

Comment: No. Dispatch_async() sends a job to a dispatch queue. Unless that queue is the main queue, the job will be run on a thread other than the main thread. A serial queue just runs it's jobs one at time, from oldest to newest. A concurrent queue may run multiple of it's jobs at the same time. Both serial queues and concurrent queues will run their jobs at the same time that the main thread is doing other things.

Comment: Think of a serial queue as a single assistant that has an in box. The assistant takes the oldest request from the inbox, completes it, then moves on. Think of a concurrent queue as a whole office full of assistants and a coordinator. The coordinator hands out jobs to multiple assistants, who work independently. The jobs are still assigned from the oldest job to the newest, but they may finish out-of-order. (A short job that's submitted later might finish after a long job that's submitted first because the longer job takes longer)

Comment: Thank you so much Duncan, this makes complete sense now. Really appreciate the detailed responses :). Helped a ton.

Comment: OHH ok never mind I understood the problem that you presented at the end of your post. Ones again thanks for all this helpful information :)

Comment: Thank you so much Duncan! If I do use one of the existing dispatch queues using the function dispatch_get_global_queue() that would mean my tasks on the new thread would run asynchronously and not serially, correct? I am not 100% sure if that is correct since I still do not have a clear definition of what an asynchronous task is. Like something happens in the background on a separate thread and everything continues as is on the main thread. In my example would that be the filtering happening in the background thread and actually installing the image on the imageView on the main thread?

Comment: The term serial queue describes how the tasks are scheduled inside the queue, not in relationship to the main thread. A serial queue can still run it's tasks asynchronously (at the same time that the main thread is doing other things.) It's only serial as far as how it runs the tasks in the queue. Using dispatch_get_global_queue() should be fine unless you need each task to run to completion before the next one starts.

Comment: Omg thank you so much for this answer... I have been looking for a straight forward answer for this distinction and I finally found one!

Comment: If you don't mind can you please explain to me which tasks are asynchronous in my example? Is it that the filteredImageFromImage method is running asynchronously on a separate thread with the installation of the image on the imageView being done on the main thread at the same time?

Comment: Close. The code inside the call to `dispatch_async(filterQueue)` runs on your background queue, which runs asynchronously on a background thread. Once the filtering is complete, it invokes a new block using `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue())`. The block of code sent to `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()` (setting the image view's image) gets invoked on the main thread.

Comment: Oh so basically ones it is done filtering an image it will go update the image view's image on the main thread. And while it is updating the image view's image on the main thread the next filter will be applied to the next image and this process will continue. Is that correct?

Comment: Ok, Thank you so much for the help ones again!

Answer (score 1):

Dispatch Queues are an abstract type the breaks away from a threading model. All you know about Dispatch Queues are that they can dispatch tasks. These tasks run in parallel with tasks from other queues.

> When you call dispatch_async does that basically switch to the queue I declared or in other words the filterQueue on a separate thread?

You cannot be guaranteed anything about tasks dispatched on `filterQueue` other than it runs in parallel with tasks dispatched on `dispatch_get_main_queue()`.

> Does the second dispatch_async (where I switch to the main queue) get called on the thread of the custom filterQueue I originally created?

You cannot be guaranteed anything about tasks dispatched on `dispatch_get_main_queue()` other than it runs in parallel with tasks dispatched on `filterQueue`.

---

Now with all the API guarantees out of the way, lets get to the current implementation.

All tasks run on the main queue are in a single thread: the main thread. When `filterQueue` is created, it is assigned a pool of threads. Any of these threads can run a task dispatched to `filterQueue`. Note: this pool of threads will **never** include the main thread.

Now the answer to both questions should be obvious. The task dispatched on `filterQueue` is run on some thread which is not the main thread. The task dispatched on `dispatch_get_main_queue()` is run on the main thread.

Comment: Thank you so much for this detailed answer... Both of your answers were so helpful. Much appreciated!

Comment: Hey Jeffery, When filterQueue is created and it is assigned a pool of threads, the task that gets put on the thread is represented by the block I have in my dispatch_async correct?

Comment: @GarryHarry yes, the block passed to `dispatch_async` is the task.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying that!